# Missing number!

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

The 4 quadruples are complete, however the 5:th one is not. Replace the question mark. (All 5 quadruples follow the same rule)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 50 ?
>  Seems that third and fourth digit are multiples of first and second digit with common factor.

Comment: This is the intended answer. I thought of it like this though: a*d = b*c. But since your reasoning obviously leads to the same answer, im giving you the tick :)